# Calculating the best position to catch as many objects as possible

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to calculate position to catch as many objects as possible with a circle that's R=9. I can gather the best target with the most other objects nearby, but its getting harder for me to get the best position inbetween my objects. The only possibility for me sounds like i have to calculate average position of all combinations i can get from the table and choose the position that has the most objects in a range of R=9.

My Table at the moment looks like this:

```
function ObjectPosition (object)
return x,y
end

table ={
object1, ---Object1 is already the one with the most other objects in a range of R=9,
object2,

object3
....
....
}
```

The ammount of objects in table changes dynamically, so i need to recalculate it few times a second.

The impossible thing for me is getting a function that will calculate all the possibilities of average positions. Thanks for your time guys!

The return from the table would need to look like this:

```
    tableTwo = {
[1] = {object1},
[2] = {object1, object3},
[3] = {object1, object2},
[4] = {object1, object2, object3},
[5] = {object2},
[6] = {object2, object3},
[7] = {object3}
}
```

Comment: Is this some kind of game engine or something?

Comment: the average position alone won't help you very much. take the average position of two points further apart than your diameter. then none of the points will be catched by your circle placed in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of very similar to ephemerr's idea:

```
function get_best_center(all_points, R)
   -- returns x_center, y_center, array of indices of points inside the circle
   local neighbors = {}   
   local diam2 = (2 * R) ^ 2
   local zone_min = math.atan2(-1, 0)
   local zone_max = math.atan2(1, 0)
   for j = 1, #all_points - 1 do
      local jx, jy = all_points[j][1], all_points[j][2]
      for k = j + 1, #all_points do
         local kx, ky = all_points[k][1], all_points[k][2]
         local dist2 = (kx - jx) ^ 2 + (ky - jy) ^ 2
         if dist2 <= diam2 then
            if dist2 == 0 then
               neighbors[j] = neighbors[j] or {{-math.huge, math.huge, j}}
               neighbors[k] = neighbors[k] or {{-math.huge, math.huge, k}}
               table.insert(neighbors[j], {-math.huge, math.huge, k})
               table.insert(neighbors[k], {-math.huge, math.huge, j})
            else
               local delta = math.acos((dist2 / diam2) ^ .5)
               local center = math.atan2(ky - jy, kx - jx)
               local azimuth_min = center - delta
               local azimuth_max = center + delta
               if azimuth_min <= zone_max and zone_min <= azimuth_max then
                  neighbors[j] = neighbors[j] or {{-math.huge, math.huge, j}}
                  table.insert(neighbors[j], {azimuth_min, azimuth_max, k})
               end
               center = math.atan2(jy - ky, jx - kx)
               azimuth_min = center - delta
               azimuth_max = center + delta
               if azimuth_min <= zone_max and zone_min <= azimuth_max then
                  neighbors[k] = neighbors[k] or {{-math.huge, math.huge, k}}
                  table.insert(neighbors[k], {azimuth_min, azimuth_max, j})
               end
            end
         end
      end
   end
   if not next(neighbors) then
      local point = all_points[1] or {}
      return point[1], point[2], point and {1} or {}
   end

   local function compare_first_elem(a, b)
      return a[1] < b[1]
   end

   local best_set = {} -- array of indices of points
   local best_x, best_y

   for k, neighbors_k in pairs(neighbors) do

      local current_set = {}
      local current_size = 0
      local come_seq, leave_seq = {}, {}
      for _, n in ipairs(neighbors_k) do
         local come, leave, idx = n[1], n[2], n[3]
         if come <= zone_min and leave >= zone_min then
            current_set[idx] = true
            current_size = current_size + 1
         end
         if come > zone_min then
            table.insert(come_seq, {come, idx})
         end
         if leave < zone_max then
            table.insert(leave_seq, {leave, idx})
         end
      end
      table.sort(come_seq, compare_first_elem)
      table.insert(come_seq, {})
      table.sort(leave_seq, compare_first_elem)
      table.insert(leave_seq, {math.huge})
      local next_come_pos = 1
      local next_leave_pos = 1
      local az = zone_min

      repeat
         if current_size > #best_set then
            local i = 1
            for j in pairs(current_set) do
               best_set[i] = j
               i = i + 1
            end
            best_x = all_points[k][1] + R * math.cos(az)
            best_y = all_points[k][2] + R * math.sin(az)
         end
         az = come_seq[next_come_pos][1]
         if az then
            repeat
               local idx = come_seq[next_come_pos][2]
               current_set[idx] = true
               current_size = current_size + 1
               next_come_pos = next_come_pos + 1
            until come_seq[next_come_pos][1] ~= az
            while leave_seq[next_leave_pos][1] < az do
               local idx = leave_seq[next_leave_pos][2]
               current_set[idx] = nil
               current_size = current_size - 1
               next_leave_pos = next_leave_pos + 1
            end
         end
      until not az

   end

   return best_x, best_y, best_set

end
```

Usage:

```
function ObjectPosition(object)
   return object.x, object.y
end

all_objects = {
   object1,
   object2,
   object3
   ....
}

-- create array of points {x, y}
local all_points = {}
for j = 1, #all_objects do
   all_points[j] = {ObjectPosition(all_objects[j])}
end

local x, y, indices = get_best_center(all_points, 9)

-- print coordinates of center of circle
print(x, y)  
-- print list of objects inside the circle
for _, idx in ipairs(indices) do
   print(all_objects[idx])
end
```

**Note:**  the circle is not centered nicely.  One or two of objects lay on its circumference.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you right and object is a point, then you can check only those circles who have 2 such point-objects on it's perimeter. There would be two circles for each pair of objects. Each of them would be determinated by it's radius and two points.

Why it would be enough? Becouse you can imaginate any best matching circle to move without loosing any objects till two objects become at it's border. So any best solution is as best as best circle of subset restricted by this "two points" rule.